# JNI linking static library: Invalid ELF header

Tags: java, linux, java-native-interface, static-libraries

I am trying to make use of a static library using JNI. Therefore I am compiling my library statically
`g++ -c -std=c++11 -o jnitest_jnitest_App.o jnitest_jnitest_App.cpp -lOtherLib`

and then package it

`ar rcs jnitest_jnitest_App.a jnitest_jnitest_App.o`

Now when I try to run my `.jar` I get the following error:

`jnitest/jnitest_jnitest_App.a: invalid ELF header (Possible cause: endianness mismatch)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method) 
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2424)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2481)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2678)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2611)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:814)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1838)
        at jnitest.jnitest.App.<clinit>(App.java:13)`

I am using a 64-bit Linux Mint 19 and Java 10 (64 bit)

Compiling the native code into a shared library gives no error with JNI. Where is the problem here?

Comment: Simply: loadLibrary relies on _dynamically_ loading libs, which wont work with a _static_ library.

Comment: Static libraries should be supported. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary-java.lang.String-

Comment: That documentation does not suggest that a static library can be loaded by
`loadLibrary`, only a dynamic (a.k.a) shared library that has itself been *statically
linked* with the VM, which it might well be. Dynamically loading a static library
is impossible. See [static-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/static-libraries/info)

Comment: @MikeKinghan Thanks for clarifying! I would like to accept your comment as an answer.

Comment: Your welcome. Done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[That documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary-java.lang.String-) does not suggest that a static library can be loaded by `loadLibrary`, only a dynamic (a.k.a shared library) that has itself been statically linked with the VM, which it might well be. Dynamically loading a static library is impossible.  See [static-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/static-libraries/info)